# Developer documentation for the Messaging Menu?

Tags: indicator, development, application-development, messaging-menu, documentation

The only documentation I have been able to find on integrating an application with the Messaging Menu is old and out of date: http://gnomejournal.org/article/67/an-introduction-to-the-message-indicator. And even that didn't have documentation for the whole API. Is there are any documentation for libindicate, either the python or C version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `libindicate-doc` package (and then look at what it installed with `dpkg -L libindicate-doc`). That should contain what you need.

Comment: This doesn't seem to contain anything massively useful to help me integrate my app with the Messaging menu; it talks, generically, about indicators, and provides a few API calls with no guidance on how to use them.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't full documentation or anything, but it may be useful
http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2011/01/16/working-with-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu

Answer (score 4):

The [Ubuntu Platform API reference](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/api/) is now online at the [Ubuntu App Developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/).

Also you'll find more links to documentation on the [resources section for the platform documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/documentation/) there.